# What is the difference between 'completeness' and 'soundness' in ZKP?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

I'm reading Matthew Green's great blog, especially the [Zero Knowledge Proofs: An illustrated primer](https://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2014/11/27/zero-knowledge-proofs-illustrated-primer/) post and I'm wondering what is the difference between *completeness* and *soundness*?

In the post, there is this part:

1. **Completeness** If Google is telling the truth, then they will eventually convince me (at least with high probability).
2. **Soundness** Google can only convince me if they're actually telling the truth.

Can I have some explanation? I don't understand the difference.

Comment: A system where the verifier always accepts is complete. Google *does* (among other things) convince you if they're trying the truth. Is it sound though?

Comment: Completeness = "statement is true $\Rightarrow$ I become convinced" // Soundness = "I become convinced $\Rightarrow$ statement was true"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The two notions are not specific to ZK, so it is in fact better to try to understand it in the context of general proof systems.

Soundness: the proof system is truthful, so whatever it proves, it is true.

Completeness: the proof system is comprehensive, so it can prove all true statements.

You can have completeness without soundness: if the proof system proves everything including falsity, obviously it is complete but not sound.

You can have soundness without completeness: if the proof system proves nothing, obviously it is sound (after all, it never proves any falsity), but not complete.